# Sorting array of structs

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

I have defined an array of structs

```
typedef struct sorting {
    int number
} SRT;

SRT *mystr = NULL;
```

which I later dynamically allocated.
and I want to sort it by the `number` int;

What kind of function do I have to write in order for qsort to do it? I have written :

```
qsort(mystr,array_index,sizeof(mystr),magic);

int magic(const void *a, const void *b) {
    int one=((const struct mystr*)a)->number;
    int two(( const struct myst*)b)->number;

    return ( one-two);
}
```

but it didn't work. How can I do it?
it throwed errors about not naming a type.

Comment: In case of "does not work", please post exactly _what_ that doesn't work. In this case, posting the compiler errors would have made it much easier to answer the question.

Comment: Also, it should be `one - two`.

Comment: @Lundin: this kind of sloppy comparison is flawed in subtle ways.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reliably sort the array with the function as written:

- It has syntax errors, some of which are typos, others indicate a confusion between types, struct tags and variable names.
- `return (one - two);` only works for reasonably small values of `one` and `two`. It will invoke undefined behavior if there is an integer arithmetic overflow.  For example, if `one == INT_MAX` and `two == -1`, the value of `one - two` is not specified by the C language and on common platform it is likely to return `INT_MIN`, a negative value, leading to incorrect sorting.

A simple solution is this:

```
int sort_function(const void *a, const void *b) {
    int one = ((const SRT*)a)->number;
    int two = ((const SRT*)b)->number;

    return (one > two) - (one < two);
}
```

The expression `(one > two) - (one < two)` evaluates to `-1` if `one` is less than `two`, `0` if they are equal and `1` otherwise. In C, comparisons evaluate to `0` if false and `1` if true.

The sorting function should be used this way:

```
qsort(mystr, array_count, sizeof(*mystr), sort_function);
```

- The second argument is the number of structures in the array pointed to by `mystr`.
- The third argument is the size of a single structure: `sizeof(mystr)` is the size of the pointer, not the size of what is points to.
- Avoid mysterious names like `magic`... use descriptive names for types, functions and variables.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

```
qsort(mystr,array_index,sizeof(mystr),magic);
```

`mystr` is a pointer to `SRT`, so you're passing in the size of a pointer to the struct, not the size of the struct:

```
qsort(mystr,array_index,sizeof(STR),magic);
```

Then there's this:

```
int one=((const struct mystr*)a)->number;
int two(( const struct myst*)b)->number;
```

`mystr` is a variable name, not a type, and `myst` isn't defined anywhere.  You need the type name here:

```
int one=((const SRT *)a)->number;
int two=((const SRT *)b)->number;
```